# static_cast to a struct type to access all of its member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a structure like below:

```
struct Param
{
    Param(const void* a, const std::vector<int>& b) : c(a), d(b) {}
    const void* c;  
    const std::vector<int> d; 
};
```

Now after creating a new instance of Param struct I store a class instance 'this' pointer in the member variable c. Later in a C Api (within C++ code) I need to refer back to the class pointer to invoke a method:

```
static_cast<ClassA*>(static_cast<Param*>(var->addr)->c)->ClassAMethod()
```

But the compiler states invalid expression type conversion. How can I refer to both Param structure variables in C Apis if the address of Param instance is stored in 'addr' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast constness away using `static_cast`, if `ClassMethodA()` is `const` then you could use `static_cast<const ClassA*>(static_cast<Param*>(var->addr)->c)->ClassAMethod()` else if you need to cast away `c`'s `const`ness then you can use `const_cast` to first cast `c` to type `void*`.

Comment: Thanks - removing c's constness resolved the issue

Comment: Casting const away should be done with care because if the actual object is const you are still not allowed to modify it and quickly end up in ub-land